# Problems adding user to database in postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, permissions

With the `postgres` user, I can select the table `users` from the `production` database.

```
sudo -u postgres psql

\c production 
You are now connected to database "production" as user "postgres".
select * from users;
....the server lists the content of the table...
```

The problem I have is that if I create a new user and grant access to the `users`, the new user cannot select it.

More especifically, I create a new user `myuser` and add all the privileges to the `production` database and to the `public` schema.

```
CREATE USER myuser WITH PASSWORD '12345678';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE production to myuser;
GRANT
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO myuser;
GRANT
```

Then, I quit, log in with the new created user `myuser`, and choose the `production` database.

```
\q
psql -h localhost -p 5432 -d production -U myuser
\c production
```

But, when I try to `select` table `users`, I don't have permissions.
What's the problem?

```
select * from users;
ERROR:  permission denied for relation users
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: what does `\dp users` show?

Comment: If I log in with `sudo -u postgres psql`, and then `\dp users`, I get 0 rows.

Comment: You need to connect to production first...

Comment: I get one row with values: Schema: public; Name: users; Type: table. Then, Access privileges; Column privileges; and Policies are empty.

Comment: Can you execute `GRANT ALL on table users TO postgres;` and `GRANT ALL on table users TO myuser;` Then `\dp users` again.

Comment: Now, I can access table `users`. I tried selecting other tables from production, and I still have the same issue. For example, `select * from budgets`, I get the message `ERROR:  permission denied for relation budgets`

Comment: Perhaps you had restrictive default privileges at the time these objects were created... `GRANT ALL on all tables in schema public  TO postgres;` , `GRANT ALL on all tables in schema public  TO myuser;` should fix it.

Comment: With either command `GRANT ALL on all tables in schema public  TO postgres;` or `GRANT ALL on all tables in schema public TO myuser;`, I get the same messages `WARNING:  no privileges were granted for "users"` `ERROR:  permission denied for relation schema_migrations`

Comment: Perhaps the `GRANT`s were run while connected to the wrong database.